# Check foreign key constraint before committing

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

Is there any way to check a foreign key constraint before committing?  The only way I know is to catch `sqlite3.IntegrityError`.

I have a Flask app using Flask-SQLAlchemy. One of the tables has a foreign key constraint.  If a row referred to by the foreign key is deleted, an `IntegrityError` is raised.  I want to give the user better feedback.  Is it possible to find out the linked rows to display?

Comment: suppose there was a way to check... and you checked, and then concurrently a row is deleted after you check but before you commit, what would your application do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the error:

```
try:
    db.session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    return render_template('error.html', msg="You can't delete this!")
```

Or even include information about the rows causing the error:

```
post = Post.query.get(123)  # object we are trying to delete
comments = post.comments  # foreign key preventing deletion

return render_template('error.html', msg="You can't delete this!", comments=comments)
```

In your template:

```
<p>Delete these comments first:</p>

{% for comment in comments %}
    {{ comment.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, i've choose a combination of your 2 solutions :-)